# Is it possible to use splash screen while opening completely independ application than our own?

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I am working on a system for gesture recognition. My application is built on WPF C#. I want to make sure that when user gives proper gesture, a splash screen appears saying "Opening XYZ application" and then that application appears. From every thread that I have come across, I have learned that Splash screen is used in the application which is starting. Hence, it must be my own application where I can change the startup code by putting splash which will work before window_load event. I want a way to do this for third party software i.e. on making a gesture "C", Chrome should be opened with a splash screen in beginning mentioning "Opening Crome".

Comment: That's not possible. Why not showing a fake screen in your application just before you start the 3rd party app. If you know, on "C" you want open chrome, then just add a screen saying so.

Comment: Create a screen in your Application which will be displayed to the User for say 10 seconds after your application identifies gesture, and in between use Process.Start method to start the required process.